# Set layout Padding and Magins

Tags: codenameone

In android, one can set layout paddings and margins between components. Is it possible  set the padding of a layout and margins between components in the GUI builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You need to set them in the theme and then apply the right UIID.

In the next version (3.7.3) of the GUI builder we will have builtin simplified styling which will make this easier.

Comment: Thanks!  It would have been nicer to do it in the GUI builder though but it's good to know it will be in the next update.